# Premake fails to create Makefile for C# library

Tags: c#, .net, linux, makefile, premake

I've just learned about **Premake** recently and decided to check it out.
It seems to work fine with C++ projects, but for some reason, whenever it encounters a C# program, it flips out.
Take this example Premake script:

```
solution "ExampleLib"
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
    project "ExampleLib"
        kind "SharedLib"
        language "C#"
        files { "../src/**.cs" }
        configuration "Debug"
            defines { "DEBUG" }
            flags { "Symbols" }
        configuration "Release"
            defines { "NDEBUG" }
            flags { "Optimize" }
```

When I generate the Makefile with `premake4 --os=linux gmake`, I get this output:

```
Building configurations...
Running action 'gmake'...
Generating Makefile...
Generating ExampleLib.make...
[string "premake.dotnet = { }..."]:28: attempt to compare nil with string
```

If I try to the run the Makefile, I get this:

```
==== Building ExampleLib (debug) ====
ExampleLib.make:12: *** missing 'endif'.  Stop.
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'ExampleLib' failed
make: *** [ExampleLib] Error 2
```

Examining the Makefile, it seems that Premake abruptly quit during the "ifndef CSC" section.

**How can I get C# projects to build with Premake?**

I am on Ubuntu 15.10 with Mono and MonoDevelop installed, if that helps.

Comment: Premake4 doesn't see many contributions these days, if you are just getting started you should use Premake5 (http://premake.github.io/). Does that version work any better for you?

Comment: @starkos works great

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to use **premake5** with the `--dotnet=mono` flag.